# How to integrate JSON bundle into Jade template?

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm new to this workflow.  I've got an Express app setup and I'm using Jade as the template engine.  I'm trying to use a tool called "gulp-bundle-assets" which bundles all of my scripts into one, and outputs them with a hash in the name (I assume to avoid cache issues).  It also includes a JSON file which is supposed to be used to integrate the scripts into your app.  It looks like this:

```
{
  "main": {
    "styles": "<link href='main-8e6d79da08.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>",
    "scripts": "<script src='main-5f17cd21a6.js' type='text/javascript'></script>"
  },
  "vendor": {
    "scripts": "<script src='vendor-d66b96f539.js' type='text/javascript'></script>",
    "styles": "<link href='vendor-23d5c9c6d1.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>"
  }
}
```

How do I include this data in my Jade template?  I saw a utility for compiling Jade templates that does variable interpolation, is that the best way to handle it, or is there something native within Jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **JADE** in a NodeJS Express Server, you may need to send data to your views. I think it is you need. Because of your data is JSON format, you need to use the JSON methods to convert into a legible format for your JADE Template view.

Try with the next sample code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

let port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'templates'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    let jsonFile = require('./public/jsondata.json');
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonFile);
    let json = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    let mStyles = json.main.styles; //You get your main styles
    res.render('index', { mainStyles: mStyles });
}).listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on' + port);
});
```

And your JADE template located in the `templates` folder with the next content:

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        #{mainStyles}
        title Hello World
```

You are passing a `mainStyles` var to the JADE template file.

> Don't forget customize your JSON file location.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for, thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: After some playing, I would like to note a couple of corrections:  1) the `require('./public/jsondata.json')` line is all that's needed, no need to stringify then parse.  2) since the json data (in this case) contains full tags, you want to use `!{mainScripts}` instead of `#{mainScripts}` to prevent Jade from escaping the string.

Comment: Thanks, this was one escaping issue that I got but I forget to specify the `!{mainScript}` expression. You would also use the `each` in Jade to loop your custom JSON Objects. Thanks for your correction.